# How to let windows 10 automatically install drivers?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers, windows-8.1, printer

I have a p.c. and a laptop, I recently update pc from windows 7 to 8.1 and my printer drivers were installed automatically on it. But when I connect printer to laptop (windows 10 may update 2004) it does not automatically install the drivers and does not print the page. USB socket is working as it works for other usbs.

Printer is Samsung SCX-4321 to be specific. (SCX -4x21 series)

And the driver installer I have is built only for windows 7.

Comment: I haven't yet upgraded to 2004, but I believe there is now an option in Settings / Update and Security to add drivers to the other updates, when available. You should check in Settings on your laptop. Sometimes, it takes a restart of both the PC and the peripheral for the driver to be properly loaded in memory, sometimes all you have to do is unplug the USB cable, wait a few seconds, then plug it back in.You can also go to Device Manager, right-click on your printer line, uninstall it along with the driver, and restart the PC with the USB cable plugged in. Windows will do the rest.

Comment: First open Control Panel. Then open devices and printers. Now right click your PC from the icons. Then click Device Installation Settings. Now click yes to confirm the dialog box. You can also do this for other devices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it worked @Didier if you can post it in answer I would mark it closed and answered

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet upgraded to 2004, but I believe there is now an option in Settings / Update and Security to add drivers to the other updates, when available.

You should check in Settings on your laptop. Sometimes, it takes a restart of both the PC and the peripheral for the driver to be properly loaded in memory, sometimes all you have to do is unplug the USB cable, wait a few seconds, then plug it back in.

You can also go to Device Manager, right-click on your printer line, uninstall it along with the driver, and restart the PC with the USB cable plugged in. Windows will do the rest.